# how to add a Horizontal separator for a bootstrap horizontal menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I m a building a horizoanl menu suing  Bootstrap 3 and here the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">          
                <a>Siginin</a>
            <?php  endif ?>
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>

      </ul>
</nav>
```

and I want to have a menu like this one :

---

### Home | About us | Services | Contact us

Just like you see above seperatros doesn expand top to bottom like having some padding on top and bottom. But , when i add | on front of a li or a the menu starts on a new line and i dont really get it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use box-shadow

```
.navbar-nav li:not(:first-child){
    box-shadow: -14px 0 0 -10px red
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmc8socb/3/embedded/result/)

[image]

Update: Update using border

```
.navbar-nav li:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 4px solid red
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmc8socb/1/embedded/result/)

[image]

Update: Using [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```
.navbar-nav li{
    position: relative
}
.navbar-nav li:not(:last-child):after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    width:2px;
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    background: red
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmc8socb/2/embedded/result/)

[image]

Comment: brilliant man ... but i want the horizaonli lines to be short on top and bottom not sttreached to touch the nav border , did u get me ?